# Mac - Output different audio streams to two separate devices

Tags: macos, audio, google-chrome, headphones

On MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6, I want to output two separate Chrome browser tab applications to two separate devices from my single macbook pro.

1) Chrome tab 1: browser game --> outputs to headphones

2) Chrome tab 2: youtube video --> outputs to HDMI-connected TV audio

I'm struggling to set this up in AudioMIDI setup.

To set up the **input**, which is the logitech headset microhpone, I set the aggregate device as input:

[image]

And the display port (TV via HDMI) and Headset as output in the Multi-output Device:

[image]

The problem is, the same audio streams are aggregated from all sources (youtube video, and browser game) to output to both the TV and headset.

What I need is two separate audio streams going to two separate devices.

Answer (score 3):

*I wrote all this before realising you want **two** routings from **one** app - that's not going to be possible. I'll leave this here for future searchers.*

There are only two apps I know can do this, both by the same company, Rogue Amoeba.

The cheaper & simpler one is [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) - $35. There is a more complex/expensive one which can also record any sound source to disk as well, called [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) - $70.

SoundSource can do all you asked & more.

There is a late third - [Boom2 & the newer Boom3D](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom/boom2.php) - but it's a notorious crasher & speaker destroyer unless you switch off everything except the routing [judging by the many questions we've seen in here about it. I've never tried it personally].

Comment: given that OP wants to route webpages, having 2 different browsers would do the trick with this solution

Comment: @LuizAngioletti - Yup. I'd kind of left that just implied rather than stated specifically, but with SoundSource, yes, that would be your fix. The Mac alone cannot do this split, it can only use one output [or many all the same with a multi-out].